# ASP.NET MVC2 and MEF - Why can't my MefControllerFactory get exports or MetaData?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mef

I am following this blog post: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/04/21/ASPNET-MVC-and-the-Managed-Extensibility-Framework-%28MEF%29.aspx and I'm having dificulty implementing the `MefControllerFactory`.

#### MefControllerFactory Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace plugme.Utilities
{

    public class MefControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
    {
        private string pluginPath;
        private DirectoryCatalog catalog;
        private CompositionContainer container;

        private DefaultControllerFactory defaultControllerFactory;

        public MefControllerFactory(string pluginPath)
        {
            this.pluginPath = pluginPath;
            this.catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(pluginPath);
            this.container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            this.defaultControllerFactory = new DefaultControllerFactory();
        }

        #region IControllerFactory Members

        public IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            IController controller = null;

            if (controllerName != null)
            {
                string controllerClassName = controllerName + "Controller";

                // "Export" isn't recognized
                // and "Metadata" (as in c => c.Metadata ) isn't recognized.
                Export<IController> export = this.container.GetExports<IController>()
                                                 .Where(c => c.Metadata.ContainsKey("controllerName")
                                                     && c.Metadata["controllerName"].ToString() == controllerName)
                                                 .FirstOrDefault();
                if (export != null)
                {
                    controller = export.GetExportedObject();
                }
            }

            if (controller == null)
            {
                return this.defaultControllerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
            }

            return controller;
        }

        public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            IDisposable disposable = controller as IDisposable;
            if (disposable != null)
            {
                disposable.Dispose();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The errors I'm getting are:

```
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Export' could not be found 
        (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   

Error 2 'System.Lazy<System.Web.Mvc.IController>' does not contain a 
        definition for 'Metadata' and no extension method 'Metadata' 
        accepting a first argument of type 
        'System.Lazy<System.Web.Mvc.IController>' could be found 
        (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error 3 'System.Lazy<System.Web.Mvc.IController>' does not contain a 
        definition for 'Metadata' and no extension method 'Metadata' 
        accepting a first argument of type 
        'System.Lazy<System.Web.Mvc.IController>' could be found 
        (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm rather confused as to why this wouldn't recognize `Export` or `Metadata`. Do you guys have any thoughts?

### Edit

I changed the line:

```
 Export<IController> export = this.container.GetExports<IController>()
                                                 .Where(c => c.Metadata.ContainsKey("controllerName")
                                                     && c.Metadata["controllerName"].ToString() == controllerName)
                                                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

To:

```
var export = this.container.GetExports<IController>()
                                                 .Where(c => c.Metadata.ContainsKey("controllerName")
                                                     && c.Metadata["controllerName"].ToString() == controllerName)
                                                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

That took care of my issues with `Metadata`. But now i hev a new error with the next if statement:

```
            if (export != null)
            {
                controller = export.GetExportedObject(); 
            }
```

error:

```
 'System.Lazy<System.Web.Mvc.IController,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object>>' does not contain a definition for 'GetExportedObject' and no extension method 'GetExportedObject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Lazy<System.Web.Mvc.IController,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That blog post was based on a preview version of MEF.  The API changed before the final release, you should use `export.Value` instead of `export.GetExportedObject()`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Do you know where I could find tutorials for the final release of MEF?

Answer (score 5):

also you can use :

```
Lazy<IController> export = this.container.GetExports<IController, IDictionary<string, object>>()
    .Where(c => c.Metadata.ContainsKey("ControllerName")
        && c.Metadata["ControllerName"].ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Equals(controllerName.ToLowerInvariant())).
            FirstOrDefault();
```

also , you need to implements the IControllerFactory function = >

```
public System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            return SessionStateBehavior.Default;
        }
```

[new export](http://hanssens.org/post/From-MEF-Preview-5-to-6.aspx)

[icontrollerfactory-implementation](http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-05-30/aspnet-mvc-fix-icontrollerfactory-implementation-upgrading-mvc_2-mvc_3)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. If the link were to break your answer, in its current form, would become useless.